# laravel eloquent one-to-one save relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Having first steps in laravel, and just hit the wall.

I Have two entities:

```
    Schema::create('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->integer('addressid')->unsigned()->nullable();
    });
```

and

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('street');
        (...)
    });

     Schema::table('company', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('addressid')
            ->references('id')->on('addresses')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Models are

```
class Address extends Model {
    public function shipyard() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'addressid');
    }
}
class Company extends Model {
    public function address() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'id', 'addressid');
    }
}
```

When I want to create these entities in DB I use one form in HTML to gather all data. Then I post request and do:

```
Route::post('/company', function (Request $request) {
    (...validation...)

    $company = new Company();
    $company->name = $request->name;

    $address = new Address();
    $address->street = $request->street;
    (...)

    $company->address()->save($address);
    $company->save();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

As a result I have two entities in DB, but the "addressid" field is null. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change relation in company (relation in address you can delete):

```
class Company extends Model {
   public function address() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Address', 'addressid');
 } }
```

Saving code:

```
Route::post('/company', function (Request $request) {
    (...validation...)

    $company = new Company();
    $company->name = $request->name;

    $address = new Address();
    $address->street = $request->street;
    (...)

    $address->save();
    $company->address()->associate($address);
    $company->save();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, @meSko! I finally found your answer after hours of struggling and searching. From the docs, I wouldn't have guessed that `associate` would be required like this: `$marketingOrigin->save();
        $marketingOrigin->contact()->associate($contact);
        $contact->save();`

Comment: Ugh, never mind. `associate()` didn't seem necessary here, and now I'm stuck with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697572/laravel-eloquent-relationship-object-stale-even-though-data-correct-in-database

Comment: Because I'd chosen to use a foreign key `contact_id` field as the primary key, I needed to set the `$incrementing` property on the Laravel Eloquent model to `false`. Wow. It took me days to figure out why the relationship wasn't saving properly. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11212#issuecomment-162249154

Answer (score 0):

```
class Address extends Model {

   // Added fillable array for mass assigment
   protected $fillable = ['street'];

   public function shipyard() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'addressid');
   }
}

class Company extends Model {

   // Added fillable for mass assignment
   protected $fillable = ['name','addressid'];

   // The second argument for the hasOne takes a foreign key not a primary key
   public function address() {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'addressid');
   }
}

 $company = new Company();
 $company->name = $request->name;
 $company->save();

 $company->address()->create($request->street)
```